# "surname" has private access in NewjFrame

Tags: java

I am currently following this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hg1S3QHFNrE&list=PLB04B4E5D9B58C13D&index=8

And I stumble in this error... What could be a possible fix for this? I'm new in programming, especially in Java. Please can you help me on this so that I could move on to other videos? I'm really a slow learner so please bear with me.

[image: errorImage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `surname` property in `NewJFrame` is having a `private` attribute , either make sure its following the `same attribute` with other property in the class or try to change it to `public` or add `getter` and `setter` for it .

Changing accessor means as follow : say u have a class Student ,same way as NewJframe class.

```
public class Student {

   private String  surName ;
   private String sex;

   public void setSurName(String surname) {

    this.surName = surname;
   }


   public String getSurName( ) {

    return this.surName;
   }


}


Student stud = new Student()

stud.surname = "abebe"; // wouldnt work becuse its private /make it public to do that
stud.setSurName("abebe"); // works fine.
```

Comment: how to change the surname property in jframe to public sir? can you please teach me?

Comment: you should post the class called NewJFrame this it will be easy ... or see the updates

Comment: newJFrame.getSurname() instead of newJFrame.surname

Comment: thank you for all the answers, solved it! Thanks again!